# How to reconnect a crashed erlang mnesia node to cluster again?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I'm learning erlang and mnesia. I have a question: how to reconncet a "crashed" erlang mnesia node to cluster again?

Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2]

What I did:

1. Two mnesia nodes: m11@deb83-11 and m12@deb83-12. They were connected
   with each other well.

   ```
   (m11@deb83-11)4> mnesia:system_info(running_db_nodes).
   ['m12@deb83-12','m11@deb83-11']
   ```
2. Then I teminated the erl shell of m12@deb83-12 by "Ctl-G" and "q"
   without stopping mnesia.
3. After that, I restarted erl shell for m12@deb83-12 node with same
   command line.
4. I found the restarted node m12@deb83-12 did not connect to
   m11@deb83-11.

   ```
   (m11@deb83-11)16> mnesia:system_info(running_db_nodes).
   ['m11@deb83-11']
   ```

Note 1. If i stopped mnesia in step#2, m12@deb83-12 would reconnect to m11@deb83-11 successfully after step#3)

Note 2. I did not create any table. There is only an empty schema in this cluster.

Thanks in advance!

Ming

Comment: Apparently all you would need to do is connect to the other node (so that `nodes().` returns the other node) and restart mnesia with `mnesia:stop().` and `mnesia:start().`. Not putting as answer I didn't check it myself.

Comment: Hi Amiramix, Thanks for your response. It's helpful. I tried to issue net_adm:ping('m12@deb83-12') from m11@deb83-11 to connect these two nodes firstly, then mnesia are connected also. Thanks:)

Comment: np, I am glad it worked :) I will put it as the answer then in case someone else will have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all you need to do is connect to the other node (so that `nodes().` returns the other node) and restart mnesia with `mnesia:stop().` and `mnesia:start().`.